# Mule 4- SalesForce connector - How to specify externalIdFieldName in Create Job Bulk V2 operation

Tags: salesforce, mule, upsert

I'm using the following:

- Mule 4.1.
- SalesForce api version 41
- Latest SalesForce connector for Mule
- Using the SalesForce connector's Create job bulk v 2 operation in a flow.

In a new Mule flow, when I use the Create job bulk v 2 operation with an upsert operation, I don't have the option to specify the externalIdFieldName.

But when I run the flow I get the message:

```
Invalid status code: 400, response body: "errorCode":"INVALIDJOB",
"message":"InvalidJob : External ID was blank for <Sobject type>. 
An External ID must be specified for upsert."
```

I'm trying to use the Bulk v2 api because it seems much simpler (don't have to worry about manually splitting the file into smaller chunks etc).

I know that the old way of doing it, via the Upsert bulk operation, has an option for ExternalIdFieldName, but that would mean implementing several extra batch processing steps, so I want to avoid it if possible.

Probably I am missing something about how to insert this value into the message/payload/attributes.

Here is what the Create job bulk v2 screen looks like:
[image: Anypoint Studio screenshot]

Here is what the Upsert bulk screen looks like:
[image: Anypoint studio screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of the Salesforce module are you using? See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeLyz.png) for reference.

To force a version update, open your project's pom.xml and edit the version manually.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-salesforce-connector</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.8</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

Latest version is 9.5.0 [source](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/com.mulesoft.connectors/mule-salesforce-connector/)

Comment: Sweet, very promising. I'm only using 9.3. I'll try it out. Thanks!